# Low Quality Post reviews are too absolute

Tags: discussion, reviewing

The latest update to the LQ queue only provides three options for improving a post: "Looks OK", which explicitly states that an answer is perfectly fine, "Edit", which allows you to edit it yourself, and "Recommend deletion", which explicitly states the answer cannot be fixed.
[image: Low Quality Posts review actions]
This doesn't allow for a situation where an answer is low quality, but can still be fixed by the user who made the post. It shouldn't be deleted outright, but it's still low-quality **at the moment**, and we want to give the user a chance to fix it.

What should be done in this situation? Is there sufficient reason to add a new action for this use case?

Comment: Given what's currently available - while this isn't the *best* solution - you could submit a comment to the post and then skip.

Comment: This seems like something that you should ask on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com), but be careful because this may have already been posted there—be sure to thoroughly search first, and consider reformulating your question before posting there.

Comment: @Wondercricket which is what I did, yeah.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 What do you mean by "reformulating"?

Comment: Wait, pause on that discussion for a moment. Could I ask you to provide an example of when this would apply? Remember, unhelpful or incorrect answers should be reviewed as Looks OK if they display even the teensiest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 "should be reviewed as Looks OK if they display even the teensiest attempt to solve the problem"; I have never been informed of this, and it seems antithetical to the concept of a Low Quality post? But, sure. [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/304857) is a review I performed where something like this would be useful

Comment: @Corsaka The [guidelines for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/805262) say: *"If you can fix without making an intrusive edit, do so. Otherwise, leave a comment explaining what's wrong and possibly downvote. **If there is no other problem, choose Looks OK.**"*

Answer (score 10):

It would be nice to have some comment templates that we could use as a base to modify, when the answer is otherwise valid but needs some clarification or extra detail that we (as reviewers and editors) cannot do ourselves. Something like this?

[image: Request clarification]

[image: Comment template examples]

**Note**: I copied the comment modal box from the 'Recommend Deletion'/'Delete' path. I opted to keep 'Link Only' in my example as it seemed relevant alongside other comments requesting improvements, rather than explaining why something would be deleted.

**Note 2**: This is a mockup for example purposes only, I only created templates targeting answers. Any system that is added for this purpose will have to also contend with low quality questions, and will likely have different comment templates.

Comment: I think this is where userscript shines: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/22581)